# What happens when scraping items from a website table using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium to scrape table data from a website. I found that I can easily iterate through the rows to get the information that I need using xcode. Does selenium keep hitting the website every time I search for an object's text by xcode? Or does it download the page first and then search through the objects offline?
If the former is true does is there a way to download the html and iterate offline using Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium uses a Web Driver, similar to your web browser. Selenium will access/download the web page once, unless you've wrote the code to reload the page.

You can download the web page and access it locally in selenium. For example you could get selenium to access the web page "C:\users\public\Desktop\index.html"

Comment: So every time I do something like: name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xp1 + row + xname).text, Selenium does not go back and hit the website?

Comment: Correct. The driver would have already done something like `driver.get(url)`. The webpage is already loaded